# For every new message(old user) a new session id is created although i am not deleting previous session id. Watson Assisstant V2 API

Tags: python, api, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

When i run the main.py in python terminal for every message not a new session id(old user) is created. But when i deploy it server each time for new message a new session_id is created even for the old user....

```
@app.route('/send_message/<string:user_message>',methods=['GET'])
def send_mesage(user_message):
    try:
        # Invoke a method
        # Create Assistant service object.
        authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('IcBMhVvVCh94QWP0u2DAfrT17-rmI9zGE4XzEoFdPDKa') # replace with API key
        assistant = AssistantV2(
            version = '2020-09-24',
            authenticator = authenticator
        )
        assistant.set_service_url('https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/8244c6b7-6d94-422f-9292-b7408871d24b')
        assistant_id = 'c9866a42-652d-4f3e-a75c-0d3e3281bc75' # replace with assistant ID

        message_input = {
            'message_type:': 'text',
            'text': user_message
            }
        #Create Session For every new User.
        session_id = assistant.create_session(assistant_id=assistant_id).get_result()
        print(json.dumps(session_id, indent=2))
        while message_input['text'] != 'quit':
            response = assistant.message(
                assistant_id=assistant_id,
                session_id=session_id['session_id'],
                input=message_input
            ).get_result()
           -------------
```

Answer (score 1):

i had to write the code outside the function..

```
  # Invoke a method
        # Create Assistant service object.
        authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('IcBMhVvVCh94QWP0u2DAfrT17-rmI9zGE4XzEoFdPDKa') # replace with API key
        assistant = AssistantV2(
            version = '2020-09-24',
            authenticator = authenticator
        )
        assistant.set_service_url('https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/8244c6b7-6d94-422f-9292-b7408871d24b')
        assistant_id = 'c9866a42-652d-4f3e-a75c-0d3e3281bc75' # replace with assistant ID
```